# Cannot upgrade in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python3

```
/home/bicky# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up systemd (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
cp: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same file
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iio-sensor-proxy:
 iio-sensor-proxy depends on systemd; however:
  Package systemd is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package iio-sensor-proxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
 iio-sensor-proxy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@bicky-H81M-S:/home/bicky#
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!!! try to type `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt-get install python3`

Comment: Same output is given

Comment: try to run `sudo apt update && sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: sudo apt update is working but dpkg --configure -a is giving same problem

Comment: you need to remove all `.rtupdate` of `python3` using `sudo rm -f /usr/share/python3/runtime.d/* ` and run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` again

Comment: Done.But some remaining problem is here "Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
 iio-sensor-proxy"

Comment: please edit your question with that output.

Comment: you have `cp: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same file` please remove it with `sudo rm -f /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` and run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` again

Comment: @abu Don't answer questions in the comments. Please post an actual answer.

Comment: @wjandrea i'm not answered the OP's question, but i try to find the real problem of the OP, thanks.

Comment: @BICKYYADAV if my answered section can solved your issue, please accept it with the green checked.

Answer (score 2):

When you have,

> dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>   python3
>   [another python3 package]
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

you need to remove all `.rtupdate` of `python3` using

```
sudo rm -f /usr/share/python3/runtime.d/*
```

and run

```
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

after you fixed the `python3` package, you have another error output :

```
Setting up systemd (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
cp: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same file
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
...
...
dpkg: error processing package iio-sensor-proxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
 iio-sensor-proxy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

the output appears cause you have two files of the resolve configuration, to fixed it run

```
sudo rm -f /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

that's will setting up your packages again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks mate, this answer helped me in a jam recently

Answer (score 0):

Check

[image]

all remove repository

back to start terminal command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: the OP problem is `python3` package instead google-chrome repository

Comment: Same problem. But  your link https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwAdB.png is not found in my software properties.There is blank.

Comment: remove gooogle-chrome repository