# dpkg error: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same file

Tags: dpkg

Friends,

I am trying to install the package `software-properties-common` on Ubuntu 20.04 but after a I run `sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common` I get the following error:

```
cp: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same
file

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
      installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
   systemd
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried this:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf 
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

After that I restarted the system and tried to install the package again but with no success. I faced the same error. Any idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: Which release are you running?  Your link /etc/resolv.conf is the default setup these days, probably a bug in the package setup if it's trying to copy that link to itself.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. I will add this to the question.

Comment: Possibly related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086067/cannot-upgrade-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @MJG did you try the answer from post linked by Terrance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ mv resolv.conf resolv.conf.old
```

And try to install again.